# what does this .container > * {} mean in css?

Tags: css, css-selectors

anyone can explain it for me , i am studing css layout. But to this code below , i stuck

```
.container > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 3 100% ;
}
```

can you explain the "greater than sign & asterisk" in this case?. 
This is a original code here:

https://codepen.io/cubigamer/pen/OgWqpB?editors=1100

Comment: I edited your question as what you ask has nothing to do with Flexbox, it is all about CSS selectors

Answer (score 1):

The `*` means **all elements**,

and the `>` means **immediate children**.

So `.container > *` means **all immediate children of container class**.

Comment: Correct, except the term *immediate children* is redundant. Children are children. I guess they would be *immediate descendants*.

Comment: @Michael_B How is it redundant? `.container > *` means **all immediate children of container class**, while `.container *` means **all children of container class** (in all levels). Am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you're missing something. I'm not talking about the selector, which is fine (and I upvoted). I am referring to the term itself. All *children* are *immediate descendants* of the parent. *Immediate children* is redundant. You can just call them *children*.

Comment: Put another way, if you have kids, they are your children. If you have grand kids, they are not your children. They are your descendants. So calling your children my *immediate children* isn't necessary.

Comment: @Michael_B Hmmm! Interesting. So the first level you're calling them *children*, and all subsequent levels you're calling them *descendants*. OK, that's fine and in that case the word *immediate* is redundant as you stated. However, not everybody understands that and often the two words *children* and *descendants* are used interchangeably, so it's probably OK to be redundant for the sake of clarity. But thank you for the note.

Answer (score 0):

Here `>` is a **CSS selector** which indicates to the **child element** and `*` means **all the elements**.

So the below example means those styles should apply in **all the elements** which has `container` class in **parent element**

```
.container > * {
  padding: 10px;
  flex: 3 100% ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Racil Hilan,@Michael_B,@Pawan Kumar. Thank